# How configure reconnecting in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I create socket.io connection with next code

```
var socket = new io.connect('http://localhost:8181', {
    'reconnect': true,
    'reconnection delay': 500,
    'max reconnection attempts': 50
});
```

But when I kill server <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> and start it again, reconnection isn't happening. But disconnect event raised on client side. What maybe reason of it?

Comment: With the default options, Socket.IO reconnects for me almost immediately when I restart the server.  Have you tried not setting any options and seeing what happens?

Comment: i tried not setting any options but reconnection isn't happening

Answer (score 38):

This is an old question, but for other people like me, who are looking how to configure reconnect in **socket.io (1.x)** here is a correct syntax:

```
var socket = new io.connect('http://localhost:8181', {
    'reconnection': true,
    'reconnectionDelay': 1000,
    'reconnectionDelayMax' : 5000,
    'reconnectionAttempts': 5
});
```

Answer (score 12):

This is an old question, but I had the same question (for a different reason) when using v1.4.5. My chat room app worked beautifully, but when I hit `Ctrl+C` in the terminal, my browser continued to loop and report ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED every few seconds until I shut it down.

Changing a previous answer just a bit gave me the solution.

For v1.4.5, here is my original code for "var socket" in my client js file:

```
    var socket = io();
```

And here is the solution:

```
    var socket = io({
        'reconnection': true,
        'reconnectionDelay': 1000,
        'reconnectionDelayMax' : 5000,
        'reconnectionAttempts': 5
    });
```

Obviously I could change the values if I want, but the important point is that this killed the never ending reconnection requests.

Comment: I am experiencing same behaviour that ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED appear after every second. Can you tell me is there any event generate if client reconnect attempt reached the given value of reconnectionAttempts:5 ? I want to show a message to a client after number of tries connection not establish

Comment: This functionality is not built in. You would have to create an alert yourself that is triggered after a specified amount of reconnection attempts.

Comment: well i got my answer there is a event name "reconnect_failed" which raise after x number of failed attempts. (https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/705)

Answer (score 11):

I realise this is an old question, but I've been having some trouble with socket io reconnecting and found this post high in the search results, so thought I would contribue. Try debugging exactly which events are firing using the following code:

```
# coffeescript. compile if you're writing javascript, obviously.

socket.on 'connect',-> console.log 'connected'
socket.on 'reconnect',-> console.log 'reconnect'
socket.on 'connecting',-> console.log 'connecting'
socket.on 'reconnecting',-> console.log 'reconnecting'
socket.on 'connect_failed',-> console.log 'connect failed'
socket.on 'reconnect_failed',-> console.log 'reconnect failed'
socket.on 'close',-> console.log 'close'
socket.on 'disconnect',-> console.log 'disconnect'
```

This should give you more insight into the state of the client socket.

Also, try looking in the Network tab of your web inspector to see if it is firing XHR requests as a fallback. Finally, in your web console, try typing io.sockets and expand it out to see whether it is actually trying to reconnect or not.

I have encountered problems with reconnect_failed not firing, and the reconnect tally not resetting. The following are links to discussions of these issues on github.

[reconnection delay - exponential back off not resetting properly](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/326)

[reconnect_failed gets never fired](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/652)

[some potential fixes/workarounds](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/226)

Answer (score 0):

reconnection delay is too small 500ms increase that, on top of that 50 retries means 500 * 50 = 25000 ms which is 25 seconds. If that doesn't help set a timeout on error event on client side to recreate the socket object (After error and some delay retry to create connection).

Comment: In doc of socket.io-client I read that "The amount of milliseconds before we try to connect to the server again. We are using a exponential back off algorithm for the following reconnections, on each reconnect attempt this value will get multiplied (500 > 1000 > 2000 > 4000 > 8000)." so it's will be bigger then 25000ms